# Convert Date Format

Tags: sql, excel, date

User updated in Excel as 01-03-2010 (as in `DD-MM-YYYY`). How do I covert this into `YYYYMMDD` in SQL? I have tried using `FromDate=Format(Sheet1.Range("A3"),"yyyymmdd")` and when I executed the SQL statement, it doesn't show any result.

Comment: I think months are specified in capital M - like MM - in your case ,format string should be yyyyMMdd

Comment: Bob, this appears to follow from a previous post, and you forget to mention that this is VBA, so the replies do not take that into account.

Comment: BTW, I tested before I answered your previous post. Does cell A3 contain, say, 13/09/2010 ? When you type `Format(Sheet1.Range("A3"),"yyyymmdd")` into the immediate window, what is returned?

Comment: A3 contains 13-09-2010 & the returned is blank.

Comment: I cannot get this to fail. How about `Sheet1.Range("A3")` What does that return?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new but when u said typed Format(Sheet1.Range("A3"),"yyyymmdd") into the immediate window, i take it as type =Format(Sheet1.Range("A3"),"yyyymmdd") in A4 cell, right ?

Comment: No, immediate window is a pane belonging to the code window. Press Alt+F11 to open a code window. If it does not include a small pane labelled "Immediate", press ctrl+G to show it. The immediate window is iseful for testing lines of VBA.

Comment: ok, re-tested the above. With Format(Sheet1.Range("A3"),"yyyymmdd"), it's blank. Similarly, it goes with Sheet1.Range("A3"). However, with input as YYYYMMDD, there is no issue with it.

Comment: That is very odd indeed, because VBA uses lower case: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was when I typed A3 with 20100913 (YYYYMMDD shd be yyyymmdd - typo error),  I hv no issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dates *on* 20100301 then you usually need to filter like this

```
WHERE MyDate >= '20100301' AND MyDate < '20100302'
```

The column MyDate is likely to have a time component so if you use equals it fails. Or you can strip the time off the column but this would cause the db engine to not use an index, so it's better to do a range query as per my example.

BTW, [yyyymmdd is the correct format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195898(office.11).aspx).

Comment: Users are not used to yyymmdd. They entered the value as dd-mm-yyyy. So I need to convert it 1st & insert them into the sql command like this:-  where MyDate >= " & FromDate & " and MyDate <= " & ToDate & "

Comment: @Bob: sorry, my yyyymmdd comment was to clarify what shekhar said (it's wrong). The date value also has to be in quotes too.